# What is the best way to make a dog remember its name?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

I have just bought Nintendogs for my 5 year old daughter, but it has been a really frustrating experience so far.

It takes forever to name the dog, and once we have finally managed that, it keeps forgetting its name.

What is the best/quickest way to name your dog and make sure it remembers it so that we can get started on the actual game?

Answer (score 2):

The best names are between two and four syllables.
Don't choose something too short or too long or it's going to be hard for your dog to learn its name.

Remember the tone you used the first time you recorded the name and remember to speak **clearly**!

If your dog understands what you said, a yellow light will appear around it. If your dog keeps being confused, you aren't pronouncing it identically each time.

After that, the dog will eventually learn its name and a window will pop up so you can write the name using the in-game keyboard.

After that remember to **keep reminding it of its name** because it is possible that your dog will forget its own name!